# Time only Column in Custom List

Tags: list, custom

I need a column in a custom list that shows time only - such as 6:00 or 23:45 - the only thing I see to possibly use is text only. Is there another better way??
thanks

Answer (score 3):

you need two columns for this. First is time and date column, and in second column would be a calculated column. apply `=TEXT([first column name],"hh:mm AM/PM"`) , it will only display the time

Comment: could you help me create a rule in a column to show an hour. The point is that I need in a column with an hour, which is visible only when in another column I have specified text "ok".

Comment: why not, pls elaborate your requirement

Answer (score 1):

If "Created" or "Modified" field is okay to use as a source, create a new calculated field with formula

=TEXT(Created,"hh:mm AM/PM")

The data type returned from the formula can be one of the below

1. Single line of text
2. Date and Time (Date & Time format)

This should give time only as in the screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Calculated field of type - Date and Time with format as "Date & Time" and use the below formula (taken from [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d5f94f68-289a-4a0c-a830-9adb2602da44/sharepoint-datetime-column-get-only-time-in-the-sharepoint?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)):

=IF(HOUR(Created)<12,HOUR(Created)&":"&Minute(Created)&" AM",
(HOUR(Created)-12)&":"&MINUTE(Created)&" PM")

The only problem I notice is that if the time is 2:00 PM, the value in calculated formula will be displayed as 2:0 PM instead of 2:00 PM. So, you may need to format a little bit.