# SharePoint Get Time from DateTime Column field

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom

I am trying to get the time value from the a DateTime field in SharePoint 2013 online.

When I try to retrieve the value of the field, it is showing only my browser time value. I am using the following code,

```
var ListItem;

function GetValue(){

   var SPContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);

   var list= SPContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);

   ListItem = list.getItemById(12345);

   SPContext.load(ListItem); 

   SPContext.executeQueryAsync(GetListItemById_Success, GetListItemById_Fail);
}

function GetListItemById_Success()
{

   var dateTimeValue = ListItem.get_item("DateTimeColumnName");

   alert(dateTimeValue);


}
```

Let me know how to get the stored DateTime Value. I'm unable to set the property set_datesInUtc(false).

Comment: see if these [suggestion](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/223299/time-only-column-in-custom-list/223303#223303) helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function GetValue() {
var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var web = '';
ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
web = ctx.get_web();
var tsList = web.get_lists().getByTitle('YOURLISTNAMEHERE');
var tsQuery = new SP.CamlQuery()("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef 
Name='ID'/><Value Type='Text'>" + '12345' + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>
</View>");
tsQuery.set_viewXml

ts = tsList.getItems(tsQuery);
ctx.load(ts);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(Success, Failed);
}

function Success() {
var tsE = ts.getEnumerator();
while (tsE.moveNext()) {
    var tsI = tsE.get_current();
    var tsCreated = tsI.get_item('DateTimeColumnName');

    var origDate = tsCreated.substr(0, tsCreated.indexOf('T'));
    var origTime = tsCreated.substring(tsCreated.lastIndexOf("T") + 1, 
tsCreated.lastIndexOf("Z"));
    alert(origDate);
    alert(origTime);
}

function Failed() {

alert("error");

}

}
```

Comment: Is this line of code correct,  var tsQuery = new SP.CamlQuery()("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef 
Name='ID'/><Value Type='Text'>" + '12345' + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>
</View>");
tsQuery.set_viewXml